# Extract columns based on another's column condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns and I want to extract the columns `temperature` and `humidity` based on the condition that column `sunhour` is above 5.

I have thought of this one:

```
df_conditions[c(“temperature”, “humidity”) , df_conditions$sunhour>5]
```

Could you please explain to me if this is correct and if not explain the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think your row/column indexes are reversed i.e. `df_conditions[df_conditions$sunhour > 5, c("temperature", "humidity")]`

Answer (score 0):

In the above mention procedure, you should filter rows first and select columns.

df_conditions[df_conditions$sunhour>5,c(“temperature”, “humidity”)]

In R we use the Pipeline operator to create a variable (<-) in dplyr package, in the same package we have 'select' and 'filter' we can solve using those functions.